# SQL Count case, where I have a unique field

Tags: sql, count, case

Have been using the code below to count how many occurrences happen each day for all stores. Was just simply counting the Site_Review_Date.

So 1 store could have 2 or more occurrence

Now I am needing the unique store occurrence each day. Keep getting stumped so reaching out for some help.

Datae example

```
Store   Site_Review_Date
90      2021-03-02
90      2021-03-02
1       2021-03-02
3       2021-03-02
20      2021-03-02
87      2021-03-02
```

so for tuesday I am looking for 5 instead of 6 if I count the dates

```
Declare  @reportStartDate date

set @reportStartDate ='2021-1-03'


SELECT 
     
    DATEPART(wk,@reportStartDate ) as Week,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate,Site_Review_Date) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS R,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS F,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS Sat,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM dbo.Map_Survey_Tracking

WHERE Site_Review_Date BETWEEN @reportStartDate/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @reportStartDate)
```

results

```
Week    S   M   T   W   R   F   Sat TOTAL
2   0   4   5   5   10  9   6   42
```

Comment: the code should use Sum not count

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,@reportStartDate ) as Week,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 0 THEN Store END) AS S,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 1 THEN Store END) AS M,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate,Site_Review_Date) = 2 THEN Store END) AS T,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 3 THEN Store END) AS W,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 4 THEN Store END) AS R,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 5 THEN Store END) AS F,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, Site_Review_Date) = 6 THEN Store END) AS Sat,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM dbo.Map_Survey_Tracking    
WHERE Site_Review_Date BETWEEN @reportStartDate/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @reportStartDate)  ;
```

I note that you are using `DATEDIFF()` for the day of the week.  `DATENAME()` or `DATEPART()` seems more transparent (although they are affected by global settings).

Comment: my unique field is store if two occurrence happen on the same day I only want to count 1.

Comment: @Michael . . . Ahh.  That makes sense.  I updated the answer.

Comment: https://biportal.cz/en/sql-count-function-how-to-count-rows-in-a-table-with-examples/  count returns the number of non null rows for a field.